# Apresentador de Slide no JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Fiz um painel de senha que tem a função de avançar ou voltar para o próximo número assim que pressiono a tecla cima ou baixo no teclado, até ai tudo bem.

Porém não queria usar um teclado, e sim um apresentador de slide, aqueles que usam no projetor que tem um laser.

O comando que eu utilizei para ativar as teclas do teclado foi esse:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
            switch (e.keyCode) {

                case 38:
                    proximo();
                    audioChamada().play;                    
                break;

                case 40:
                    anterior();
                    break;
                }
        }
```

Porém gostaria que também funcionasse no apresentador de slide só que não vai.
Queria uma sugestão.

Comment: E esses passadores de slide não simulam as teclas do teclado?

Comment: então achei que iria simular mas não funciona, o que eu percebi que a barrinha lateral da página mexe mas a função para mudança de números não vai.

Comment: Tente usar a referencia das teclas de PageUp e PageDown e não de UpArroe e DownArrow

Comment: Ou dá um `console.log(e.keyCode)` e vê qual é a tecla que ele simula.

Comment: o comentário do Hugo resolveu meu problema, realmente era só ativar os códigos do PageUP e PageDown, muito obrigado a todos!